# Solaris Shell/Terminal emulator windows

Tags: windows, shell, solaris

Hi im looking for a solaris simulating windows terminal to execute some environment specific scripts i have. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe anything like that exists. Your best option is probably a Solaris VM. You can download one and VirtualBox from Oracle.

[Here is a blog entry that discusses use of the VM](https://blogs.oracle.com/observatory/entry/solaris_11_express_virtualbox_vm)